# What laws in the state of Pennsylvania relate to the release of domestic animals?

Tags: feral, legal

What laws are in place in the state of Pennsylvania around the release of animals considered to be domestic pets; Cats, Dogs, Rabbits, etc?

References related to enforcement (*penalties and/or lack of enforcement*) are encouraged in answers.

Answer (score 1):

Domestic Animals are addressed under [Title 3,  CHAPTER 23, DOMESTIC ANIMALS](http://www.legis.state.pa.us/cfdocs/legis/LI/consCheck.cfm?txtType=HTM&ttl=03&div=0&chpt=23) where they are defined

> "Domestic animal."  An animal maintained in captivity. The term also includes the germ plasm, embryos and fertile ova of such animals.

There is no mention of abandonment in this chapter. The only mention of release is

> it shall be unlawful to release onto a swine hunting preserve a male swine that has not been sterilized.

Pennsylvania does have a [Dog law (Act) § 459-101.](https://www.animallaw.info/statute/pa-dog-law-chapter-8-dogs-consolidated-dog-laws#s101) which only makes it unlawful to abandon dogs.

> (1) It shall be unlawful for any person to abandon or attempt to abandon any dog within the Commonwealth. Anyone convicted of abandoning or attempting to abandon any dog within the Commonwealth shall pay a fine of not less than $300 and not more than $1,000, plus costs.

According to a local news article [Pennsylvania among states with highest pet abandonment, neglect cases](http://www.wpxi.com/news/news/local/pa-among-states-with-pet-abandoment-neglect/nQFHP/)